# Ebay doesn't work with tree style tab & imagus in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile, firefox-quantum

There are couple of things, both happened at the same time so I think they're related, ebays favicon stopped displaying in Tree Style Tab and imagus stopped working on ebay. Icon shows normally in default tab toolbar but I have it disabled because of the mentioned addon.

This only happens in my current profile, in other profiles they work well.

So this is pretty much a problem with my profile but I can't figure out what it is and I don't want to refresh the profile. Do you guys have any thoughts on what it might be? I'm curious what could cause this.

What I've tried so far:

- Manually disabled all addons and enable only **imagus** / only **tst**
- Reinstall both addons
- Cleared Cache and Cookies

none of these solved the problem.

Comment: Yes on another profile everything worked with the same addons. I just reset preferences and that fixed it. Not sure exactly what it was.

Comment: And now it's back to exactly the same behavior, a few days after the reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the tracking protection future of firefox that was causing this

Answer (score 0):

On my computer (Windows 11 Pro, FF v.115.8.0esr 64-Bit) eBay selling pages style didn't load and I know from many similiar cases, no matter the operating system. Other suffer from broken shipment tracking page or buttons that become non-interactive.
Turning on/off tracking protection didn't help in my case and with todays FF version its not about that entirely. A few years ago some people reported changing the user-agent-string or disabling addons like "uBlock Origin" or "Ghostery" would have worked - I tried it in vain, so cannot confirm that.

[image]

Solution:

I tracked down the issue instead to one specific setting (inside file "prefs.js" inside FF profile). You have to change the following line:

From: `user_pref("beacon.enabled", false);`

To: `user_pref("beacon.enabled", true);`

Just to make sure, delete the cache for ebay website too (lock symbol) and reload the page.

Info: "beacon.enabled" defines whether websites are allowed to send background telemtry to their servers even after tab is closed. That means, eBay either relies on that for real or they ban everyone who disabled this tracking method. It's annyoing one has to allow crucial parts of tracking in Firefox to make ebay loads the selling article page (its style to be specific). In the moment there seems to be no other solution that actually works.